# Can't call ruby module method

Tags: ruby, module

cat module1.rb =>

```
module Module1

    def add(a,b)
        return a+b
    end

    def subtract(a,b)
        return a-b
    end

end
```

cat call.rb =>

```
#!/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

include './Module1.rb

temp = add(5,2)
print temp
print "\n"
```

ruby call.rb =>

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- Module1 (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from call.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone fix it ?

Comment: The code you have posted and the error message don't match up. The error message says that you have an error when calling `require` on line 3 of `call.rb`, but there is no call to `require` on line 3 or anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Place two files in the same directory.  Call the first one module1.rb and make it look exactly like this:

```
module Module1
  def add(a, b)
    return a + b
  end
  def subtract(a, b)
    return a - b
  end
end
```

Call the second one call.rb and make it look exactly like this

```
require './module1.rb'
include Module1

temp = add(5,2)
print temp
print "\n"
```

At the commandline, run `ruby call.rb`.  You should see an output of `7`.

Comment: still error,   <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- ./Module1.rb (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from call.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I named the file Module1.rb and it worked for me.  I see now that I misread the question.  The file is called module1.rb.  I edited my answer.  Looks like Andrew Nesbitt found this already.  It is still good practice to have the `require` however.

Comment: still error, call.rb:4:in `include': wrong argument type String (expected Module) (TypeError)
 from call.rb:4:in `<main>'
user1@user1-desktop:~/rbtest$ vim module1.rb

Comment: Odd, it works perfectly for me and I get 7 printed.  Are the two files in the same directory?  Are you running `ruby call.rb` from the command line?  Is your call.rb _exactly_ like my answer?  I wonder because you got an error on line 4....

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using Ruby 1.9?

Then try

```
require_relative 'module1'
include Module1

temp = add(5,2)
puts temp
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

`require` loads a file from Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`. If you want to load a file relative to the current file, then you need to use `require_relative` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should require the file before including.

```
require 'module1.rb'
include Module1
```

And make sure the two file are in same directory.